# Is it possible to run pydev connected to a virtualbox instance?

Tags: python, linux, virtualbox, pydev

At the moment I'm developing using a simple editor, putty, and a VirtualBox instance of a linux server. I've heard good things about pydev and would like to try it, but I'd like to use the python install & terminal from my VirtualBox guest OS.

I'm already using a Shared Folder with VirtualBox so my Guest OS can see my local files.

Is it possible to tell pydev to use this "remote" host over SSH to execute its python-related commands?

**UPDATE:**

My main environment is windows, but I'd also like to be able to work this way on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your host box is windows.

I also assume that pydev will run under linux (since it's eclipse based). Are you ok installing the dev environment on your linux server?

In which case:

1. install and run [xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) on your windows box
2. Install eclipse & pydev on your linux box
3. Configure [x forwarding in putty](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html)
4. Run pydev through putty and you'll have the UI appear on your windows machine like normal

Then pydev will be running on the linux box quite happily, and so using the python environment on there.

Downsides: you will need to install the X libraries & java on your server (installing eclipse using your normal package manager should be enough), although you won't need to run X itself, since that's what Xming is for.

Comment: Will this impact heavily on the RAM usage on the guest linux OS? Currently its limited to 256MB to catch memory errors early on.

Comment: Is this possible on OSX also?

Comment: Frankly, yes, it would impact the RAM usage as I don't expect pydev is particularly lightweight - that would all be running on the server with this solution. You might want to use task manager or process explorer to look at how much ram it uses in windows - expect a similar amount under linux.

Comment: I believe OSX uses X windows, so this should work as both the client and the server in osx. However, I've never run osx myself, so can't vouch for it.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, see how I get on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Let me understand the situation, Windows is hosting the virtualBox which host the linux.
You connect to the linux using putty.
Python files are on the linux machine and you wish to edit them from your Windows using pydev. So either do that using the sharing features of virtual box (which can work for you in vboth ways) or use ssh to edit the linux files from windows.
both options would be valid for MacOSx AFAIK

Below you cna find the way to do so over SSH

You map a netwrok drive over SSH and then you can access the files via that drive letter
see more at

http://www.neophob.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/103-Map-a-Network-drive-net-use-over-SSH.html

and

http://smithii.com/map_a_network_drive_over_ssh_in_windows